# Duplicate class error when building on cmd with gradle but not when build in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

When I build on the command line with

```
./gradlew clean build
```

I get the following error

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/Gson$5.class

I know one of the JAR's I need from a third party include GSON but I am not sure what the other item is that is using GSON.

What I can't understand is that when I build with Android Studio. I don't get this error. I have to build with cmd line on Jenkins for our release builds.

Below is the dependency tree

```
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.<vendor>.<package>.api:<package>:5.2.6
+--- com.<vendor>.<package>.<package>-deliverable:5.2.6    //I know this jar has GSON in it
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1
+--- net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.+ -> 2.8.2
|    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.+ -> 7.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.+ -> 7.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.+ -> 7.8.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0
\--- com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.4
```

Removed the third party library names, I am at a bit of loss here trying to figure out why this works on Android Studio but not manually.